# How do i save base 64 string to image using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I do this in Windows Form application and it saves correctly.

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\jasmine\Desktop\test.jpg";
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(rd["SignatureBase64"].ToString());
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true, true);
image.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Now i want to do the same using ASP.NET to save the image to a jpg file. How can i do this. I have not tried such in ASP.NET before

Comment: So try it and then ask the question. Note that you'll need a reference to System.Drawing.

Comment: First of all, you can use the same code in ASP.NET. Second, you don't need the `Image` class in Winforms either, unless you need to *convert* an image from another format to JPG. Otherwise you can simply save the file with `File.WriteAllBytes("test.jpg",imageBytes)`. The same works in ASP.NET.